# MySQL Queries with a range on the Join (speed issue)

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT formatted_journeys.*, MAX(speed) 
FROM formatted_journeys 
JOIN tracker.g_log 
   ON imeiid = vehicle 
   AND g_logid BETWEEN start_g_log AND end_g_log 
GROUP BY id
```

however, it seems to be extremely slow. Here's the explain for that query.

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+-------------------------------+-------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type | possible_keys                 | key   | key_len | ref                               | rows | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+-------------------------------+-------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | formatted_journeys | ALL  | vehicle,start_g_log,end_g_log | NULL  | NULL    | NULL                              |  824 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | g_log              | ref  | PRIMARY,Dupes                 | Dupes | 4       | motrak.formatted_journeys.vehicle | 1985 |   100.00 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+-------------------------------+-------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.02 sec)
```

The tables are as follows:

formatted_journeys:

```
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| start_g_log     | int(11)          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| end_g_log       | int(11)          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| start_latitude  | decimal(18,12)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| start_longitude | decimal(18,12)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| end_latitude    | decimal(18,12)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| end_longitude   | decimal(18,12)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| start_location  | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| end_location    | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| distance        | decimal(10,5)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| start_date      | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| end_date        | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| vehicle         | int(11)          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| private         | bit(1)           | NO   |     | b'0'    |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Indices:

```
+--------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table              | Non_unique | Key_name    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| formatted_journeys |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | id          | A         |         830 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| formatted_journeys |          1 | vehicle     |            1 | vehicle     | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| formatted_journeys |          1 | start_g_log |            1 | start_g_log | A         |         830 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| formatted_journeys |          1 | end_g_log   |            1 | end_g_log   | A         |         830 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+--------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

tracker.g_log:

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| g_logid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| imeiid    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| latitude  | decimal(18,12)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| longitude | decimal(18,12)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| speed     | int(4)           | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| bearing   | int(4)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| distance  | decimal(10,5)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| eventcode | int(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status    | int(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date      | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Indices:

```
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| g_log |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | g_logid     | A         |       31760 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| g_log |          0 | Dupes    |            1 | imeiid      | A         |          16 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| g_log |          0 | Dupes    |            2 | date        | A         |       31760 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| g_log |          0 | Dupes    |            3 | eventcode   | A         |       31760 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| g_log |          1 | speed    |            1 | speed       | A         |         423 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

Now I know that the filesort isn't a good thing but how would I get rid of it?

Comment: @Arion: Thanks for the edit, was just about to do it.

Comment: No problem.. I Could not see what you where asking:P

Comment: Things might look much better if you had `journey_id` field in `tracker.g_log` table.

Comment: Unfortunately the tracker.g_log table can't be changed. That was my first thought.

Comment: Are you sure that you need the result for all journeys as result of the query, or you are going to apply an additional condition or limit?

Comment: Unfortunately I do, client requirements are a sod! - There might be times where an additional limit is used, but not always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will hardly get rid of `Using temporary; Using filesort`, but the query might be faster.

First, try to rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT id, MAX(speed) as max_speed
  FROM formatted_journeys 
  JOIN tracker.g_log 
    ON imeiid = vehicle 
      AND g_logid BETWEEN start_g_log AND end_g_log 
  GROUP BY id) as maxspeeds
JOIN formatted_journeys USING (id);
```

Then, you can try to force the query to use a coverage index, though that is not easy for the query.

First try: add a composite index `(vehicle, start_g_log, end_g_log)` and look in explain whether it is used (you should see "Using index" there)

Comment: @ridecar2, then you can try to add a composite `(imeiid, speed)` and try to force both indexes using hints. If that doesn't work, I personally do not see, a way to speed it up. But I may be not enough experienced =)